# Where is secure boot UEFI enabled Ubuntu 12.04.2?

Tags: boot, uefi, samsung

currently I'm downloading 
ubuntu 12.04.2 from official

http://www.ubuntu.com/download

I just read on [m.h-online.com](http://m.h-online.com/open/news/item/Secure-Boot-comes-to-Ubuntu-12-04-2-LTS-1804203.html?from-classic=1) and on [linux.com](https://www.linux.com/component/content/article/135-distronews/699990-secure-boot-comes-to-ubuntu-12042-lts) that Secure UEFI Boot version have been released.

So I wanted to know if I'm downloading that secure Boot UEFI version from (http://ubuntu.com/download) or I have to download that Secure boot UEFI edition from somewhere else?

Since I have a Samsung laptop and I don't want to take the risk of bricking it.

Comment: @ANiK3T it even SAYS in your link where you can download it !? So why the question?

Comment: Listen
recently some samsung laptops were bricked permanently while booting linux to them
as i googled more i found that Ubuntu 12.04.2 has that UEFI fix present in it.
Currntly Ubuntu 12.04.2 is on my downloading list which i downloaded from (ubuntu.com/download)

so my question is where is that UEFI FIXED version of ubuntu 12.04.2?
Is it seperate version (download) 
or is it already there in ubuntu.com/download which im downloading now?

Comment: If your Samsung Laptop has UEFI don't install any OS.  Its a firmware bug which Samsung are aware of.  This is not just a Linux issue Windows can **Brick** the Computer too.  It's not an issue with older non UEFI laptops.  If yours is UEFI I would return it to the supplier for a refund.  I'm sure Samsung will fix this but its not fixed today and you risk bricking the machine.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to not run ***ANY*** OS in EFI mode on recent Samsung computers. As [described by Matthew Garrett,](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/22855.html) this firmware can be bricked even from Windows. The initial Linux kernel fix just fixed the most common path to the underlying bug, but the bug remained. I've heard a vague report that there may be a *second* workaround in even more recent kernels, but I don't have details and I don't know if this really completely eliminates the risk.

Given all this, my advice is to do one of three things:

- Return the computer to the store for a refund and buy something that's not defective.
- Wipe the hard disk clean and re-install everything you want to use in BIOS mode rather than in EFI mode.
- Put the computer back in its box until Samsung releases a fixed firmware.